# Not able to rotate multiple objects

Tags: error, mirror

I am working with this (https://drive.google.com/file/d/13ADw3pDweaAi5ZPVZdCiqL7IV1mQ708u/view?usp=sharing) car model, and I want to select the whole model and rotate it so the car faces the y axis. I have tried multiple techniques like parenting it to an empty, and changing the 3d cursor and pivot point but the car always ends up weird and the parts rotate by themselves. I downloaded this model online so I'm not sure whether it was a modelling issue or something. Help!

Answer (score 1):

You have a *Mirror* modifier on several objects that are part of your wheels, they all use 2 mirror objects that are invisible in preview and that are called *mirror_plane.001* and *mirror_plane*:

[image]

If you move the wheel objects without selecting these mirror objects it will mess up the mirror effect, so you either need to apply the *Mirror* modifiers of all these objects, or select these mirror objects when you want to move your whole car.

You could also simply parent every objects, including these mirror objects to an empty or to a main piece of your car.

Comment: Oh! Thanks so much! This had been driving me bonkers lol!